# Include no HTML

Tags: html, include

Eu aprendi a fazer o include via PHP

E agora eu preciso fazer a mesma coisa mas em HTML, mas criei uma navbar em um arquivo separado para meu código ficar mais limpo, e não estou conseguindo colocar minha navbar no index.html.

Sempre fiz assim mas agora nao posso utilizar o PHP para auxiliar na conexão

[image: desc]

Comment: Depende do servidor de páginas. O Apache, por exemplo, tem um [módulo para fazer include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) em HTML, o IIS [também permite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525940(v=vs.90)), assim como o [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) - Não é da especificação do HTML, mas boa parte dos servidores de página tem o recurso. Consulte com quem configurou o servidor que pretende usar.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Sem PHP não tem como, no HTML você tem que fazer em arquivo único, não tem como montar parte por parte e depois ir incluindo igual no PHP.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não é uma verdade absoluta essa informação. Depende do servidor de páginas. O Apache, por exemplo, tem um [módulo para fazer include](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html) em HTML, o IIS [também permite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525940(v=vs.90)), assim como o [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) (grande parte dos servidores populares de página tem o recurso - não é da especificação do HTML, mas não precisa de linguagem cliente, seja PHP ou alguma das muitas outras existentes).